# .net winforms custom control with wrong sizes in designer

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

In my solution, I have a project in which I'm creating custom controls.
When I build that project, I can insert the custom control in another project through the designer. All works well

With one of those controls however, and one of the forms, I'm having trouble.
It's supposed to be a control of fixed size, with a listbox, a button, a groupbox and little else. But when I drag it from the designer, into this particular form, the listbox and button sizes are all wrong, way bigger than the original. 
This doesn't happen with other controls nor with other form. The properties I see in the properties window for all the forms (except for Text, Font, Name...) are the same.

I'd appreciate your ideas and guidance as to how to look for what's going on. I'm quite new with VS and .NET

Thanks

Comment: Check the AutoScale mode properties. (It will be "Inherit" by default, so check the parent's -- e.g. Forms -- properties as well. Try changing this value to see if the issue is fixed.)

Comment: @pst, this was definately the issue. AutoScale was set in all forms to Font, but the text font size of that particular form was about double than the rest. When I reduced it, all the other controls shrank but if I fix all of them, it should all work

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when that control was designed on a machine that had a different video adapter DPI (dots per inch) setting.  When you use it on yours, the control automatically rescales itself to accommodate your machine's DPI setting.  So that it appears just as large as it did on the original machine.  In inches, not pixels.

This is normally highly desired, you don't want to mess with the control's AutoScaleMode property.  Because if you do, it will misbehave on the user's machine when it has a different DPI setting.  Fix your problem by editing the control's Designer.cs file.  Look for code at the bottom of the InitializeComponent() method that assigns the AutoScaleDimensions property and make it the same as a control created on your machine.  You may then also need to tweak font sizes.

Comment: Thanks. For this particular case I want the app to be of fixed size, good-old 800x600 pixels, not resizeable. It's ok but not necessary for everything to rescale up in bigger screens. However, it can't have a control or its fonts getting bigger (in pixels) in a particular computer, if I fix the form size to 800x600. I can't test it in many pcs so it's good to learn the good practices

Comment: Hmm, bad idea.  This is not going to look good on a 'retina' display with a 4096 x 2304 resolution.  That 800x600 window turns into a postage stamp.  That future is tomorrow.  But today's problem are the fonts, 10 points on a high resolution display is going to require a bigger box.  Autoscaling makes the box bigger, automatically.  You already got such a display, wherever that control came from.  If you really want this problem out of your life then consider WPF, all sizes are in inches instead of pixels.

Comment: That would be great, but it's not a priority in this case. They guy's that will be using this unfortunately have old computers, and probably still have 8 years until high definition and 20 until retina displays. The priority is to have the guarantee that an old 800x600 screen (I don't know of how many inches) will be able to see the whole form, without scrollbars and manual resizing. You say I can have the best of both worlds in some simple manner, like with some AutoScale setting? Unfortunately I'm too deep into winforms and have little time left, to move to WPF in this project...

Comment: 20 years, hah!  I'm trying to think back to 1992, computer technology was moving fast back then.  Fairly sure I just switched to Windows 3.0 from MS-DOS around that time, happily giving up on the DOS extender nightmares.  Machine was a 486 clocked at 33 Mhz, got 86 times more today.  With 4 megabytes of RAM, got 2048 times more today.  Hard drive was around 40 megabytes, got 25,000 times more today.  Display was a big-ass 14 inch CRT at 640 x 480 resolution.  Running at 96 dpi, like yours today.  Apple is fixing that awful stall, bless them.

Comment: That's right. I'm sure they are still using a couple of those machines with MS-DOS somewhere in the public sector here... C'est la vie